# Login loop in Kali Linux after updating/upgrading

Tags: linux, video, xorg, kali-linux, gdm

I've updated/upgraded my Kali Linux and now I'm stuck in a login loop.
I've tried everything in console (Ctrl+Alt+F2):

```
dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo reboot
```

Then also tried

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install cinnamon-control-center-data
gdm3 --version
apt-get --reinstall install gdm3
apt-get --reinstall install gnome
apt-get --reinstall install gnome-shell
dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
reboot
```

Also tried installing lightdm but the problem persists

I empited /var/log and tried again, and then saw the file Xorg.0.log was generated, but cannot get which is the problem. I guess maybe something related to video...

[/var/log/Xorg.0.log](https://pastebin.com/S79XESea)

[/root/.xsession-errors](https://pastebin.com/d2GCitxZ)

Comment: So after entering user/password, it gets back to that screen?
Are you able to log in on tty2?

Comment: Do you login as root or did you create a user?

Comment: @davidbaumann Yes, after entering user/pass i get same login screen again. I can login on tty2 and logged in as root

Comment: Check ~/.xsession-errors

Comment: @davidbaumann i've edited question and added /root/.xsession-errors output but I cannot figure out any problem... https://pastebin.com/d2GCitxZ

Comment: I've also deleted /root/.Xauthority and /root/.ICEAuthority and restarted, but nothing... loop still on

Comment: After "apt-get upgrade", did you do a "apt-get dist-upgrade"? You don't usually want to update all the library's and dependencies without actually updating the distribution. I must say, Kali Linux is extremely easy to break an installation. I have come to just update my Kali installations by formatting and reinstalling over the kali partition with a USB stick and new stable rolling image. It's actually about 50% faster than doing the update/upgrades. Honestly, I haven't had a broken installation since I started doing that. If you haven't already done so, check out the Kali Linux revealed book.

Comment: https://www.kali.org/download-kali-linux-revealed-book/

Answer (score 1):

Hi there I have been having similar problems as well, but I was able to solve it by creating a new user and specifying a home directory using

```
sudo useradd -m username 

sudo passwd < enter your password for the account >
```

Finally I used

```
startx
```

(assuming that you installed x-window-sytem)

Voila I ended up in the graphical interface instead of typing in my credentials and ending back at the login screen.

P.S.: I was initially setting up my Kali Linux OS when I wanted to add another user from root and realized that the login GUI would keep rebooting after entering credentials for the new user account. After hours of work I was finally able to get to a GUI for the non-root account. I am not sure if this is a permanent fix or merely a onetime fix, but I will keep working on it and let you know!

Answer (score 1):

I'd been having similar issues, Kali booting to the sign-in. After signing in, it would go black and then back to the login screen. After hours and hours of searching, [this tutorial](https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-ubuntu-login-loop/#:%7E:text=Log%20in%20to%20the%20Shell,-Start%20Ubuntu%20like&text=Let%20it%20get%20all%20the,a%20black%20and%20white%20terminal.) fixed it. Despite the tutorial being for Ubuntu, it works for Kali.

## What I did

---

Press `CTRL` + `ALT` + `F2` to enter the command line while on the login screen.

Login **using your user** profile. `.Xauthority` won't show up if you don't (at least it didn't for me).

Enter `ls -lah` and look for `.Xauthority`

[image: .Xauthority]

Ensure that `.Xauthority` is owned by you, not root. If where it says `josi` yours says `root`, type `sudo chown yourusername:yourusername .Xauthority`.

Then you should be able to press `CTRL` + `ALT` + `F7` to return to the login screen.